# How to Update html content of WebView without refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, webview

I have an android webview where the content of the html page is produced from a string passed to the html page and dependent on the users actions. Is it possible to update the string and hence the content of the html page without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [hash routing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange), or the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) to prevent the page from refreshing when the url changes. There are many wrapper libraries out there:

- [Page.js](https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/)
- [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/#Router)
- [Routie](http://projects.jga.me/routie/)

When a page change is detected, you will need to fetch the new data with an [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) call, then render the results onto the page.